# Google Play reject Cordova application 'cause contains security vulnerabilities for users

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-play, apache-cordova

I developed an application on Apache Cordova, I followed all the steps to generate the .apk to upload on Google Play. I tried many times but Google's response is the same:

> *We rejected APP, package ID com.xxx.app, for violating our dangerous products policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of
>   your app is still available on Google Play. This app uses software
>   that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Below is the list of
>   vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK versions that were detected
>   in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as
>   possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   **Vulnerability Apache Cordova: The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1**.*

I have the latest version of Cordova (5.4.1).

The following will detail the steps that I followed for installation and project development:

- Start the download of Cordova from the console Node.js using the command npm install -g Cordova.
- Install Java: version 1.8.0_65.
- Install Android SDK.
- Add Java and SDK to PATH.
- I downloaded the necessary components of the Android SDK.
- Create the project through the commands. (Cordova create Projectxxxx).
- Add the Android platform.
- I copied my application code in the www folder.
- Add the plugins needed for my project: splashscreen and sqlite.
- I tested the application on the Android emulator and other mobile phones. All good. Runs perfect.
- To create the signed APK file, these are the steps:

  -Cordova build --release android. (This generated the android-release-unsigned.apk on platforms / android / build / outputs
  / apk).

  -Then, I generated the keystore.

  -After the jarsigner.

  -Finally: zipalign.
- I upload end-app.apk to Google Play.

Another detail that I have is that cordova.js generated version is 4.1.1. But the console version is 5.4.1 (Command: Cordova -version). 
I did everything by node.js console.

Attemps:
I uploaded an APK without js components. Only with cordova.js and it not worked.
I installed all over again in a newly installed windows and neither worked.

My version is higher than 3.5.1. I can not find the solution.

Comment: Have a look at the version of your cordova.js in platforms->android->assets->cordova.js in the near of row 20 you find the version.

Comment: Hi, @Joerg. Yes.. is 4.1.1. I mention in the description.

Comment: Are you loading javascript code from a server?

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is not just that PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL is wrong, but the default cordova used is ancient ( it was 3.7.1 on mine ).  To resolve this you need to install a newer version in the project.  You can specify this on the command line, much like npm does.

```
cordova platform update android@4.1.1
```

Or you can specify it in your config.xml

```
<engine name="android" version="4.1.1" />
```

That may need 'spec' instead of 'version' depending on how current you cordova install is.  At this point, they are up to 5.1, and you can use 'latest' instead of a specific version number.

The next headache will be the point of the patch, which locks down network access.  I am now getting 404 errors on all my ajax calls to our server.  Access was the root of the security problem, so this isn't a big surprise.  I am still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found a previous corodva version in a plugin, in my case was facebook connect; I deleted this plugin and upload again, its work form me. You may search PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL in your project, is posible that some plugin have other cordova version.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this problem almost for a week. Solution:
There was a cordova.js file within www/lib/cordova folder that doesn't get updated when you update cordova and ionic. Open the file and look for var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL. If the version is not 4.1.1 at the time of this post, update it with another copy of the file that is somewhere in your main directory.